# awk print column for a given range

Tags: awk, tabular

My data looks like that:

```
0.000000 0.071429 0.071429 0.857143 
0.071429 0.428571 0.071429 0.428571 
0.357143 0.214286 0.357143 0.071429 
0.000000 0.714286 0.000000 0.285714 
0.000000 0.571429 0.000000 0.428571 
0.428571 0.357143 0.071429 0.142857 
0.000000 0.071429 0.071429 0.857143 
0.071429 0.000000 0.928571 0.000000 
0.000000 0.071429 0.000000 0.928571 
0.000000 0.285714 0.000000 0.714286 
0.142857 0.000000 0.785714 0.071429
```

I want it to look like that:

```
AC name_of_the_file.txt
00 0.000000 0.071429 0.071429 0.857143 
01 0.071429 0.428571 0.071429 0.428571 
02 0.357143 0.214286 0.357143 0.071429 
03 0.000000 0.714286 0.000000 0.285714 
04 0.000000 0.571429 0.000000 0.428571 
05 0.428571 0.357143 0.071429 0.142857 
06 0.000000 0.071429 0.071429 0.857143 
07 0.071429 0.000000 0.928571 0.000000 
08 0.000000 0.071429 0.000000 0.928571 
09 0.000000 0.285714 0.000000 0.714286 
10 0.142857 0.000000 0.785714 0.071429  
XX
//
```

How can I awk $1 for a range (from 00 till the file ends)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're after?  Why do you mention `$1`?  Are you looking for extra information at the top and bottom of the file?  Are you somehow hoping to filter the data?  If so, how?  What happens if there are more than 100 lines in the file?  What happens if there are several files in the input?  What goes after the end of the previous file? What comes before the beginning of the next file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 { print FILENAME } { printf "%02d %s\n", FNR - 1, $0 }' infile
```

Output:

```
infile
00 00 0.000000 0.071429 0.071429 0.857143 
01 01 0.071429 0.428571 0.071429 0.428571 
02 02 0.357143 0.214286 0.357143 0.071429 
03 03 0.000000 0.714286 0.000000 0.285714 
04 04 0.000000 0.571429 0.000000 0.428571 
05 05 0.428571 0.357143 0.071429 0.142857 
06 06 0.000000 0.071429 0.071429 0.857143 
07 07 0.071429 0.000000 0.928571 0.000000 
08 08 0.000000 0.071429 0.000000 0.928571 
09 09 0.000000 0.285714 0.000000 0.714286 
10 10 0.142857 0.000000 0.785714 0.071429
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks. Can you show adding the name of the file as first line?

Comment: Using `FNR - 1` instead of `num++` is more idiomatic. @user1286528: See glenn jackman's comment for a way to include the filename.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Good point. Added to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear what the real question is.  Superficially, this should do the job:

```
awk '{ if (line++ == 0) { print "AC " FILENAME; } printf("%.2d %s\n", NR-1, $0); }
     END { print "XX\n//" }'
```

Comment: +1 although `NR == 1 {print "AC", FILENAME}` is a little tidier for the first bit.

Comment: That's certainly another way to do it.  And probably using `gawk`'s FNR with `FNR == 1 { print "AC " FILENAME }` would get the new file name before each new file (with it being open to question whether either the XX or the // or both should go after the prior file and before the new AC line).  Such details are not (yet) specified in the question.

Comment: `FNR` isn't `gawk`-specific. It's specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

Comment: Fair comment, @DennisWilliamson.  It wasn't in the `awk` from 7th Edition UNIX™ which is when I learned the language (ouch!).